# Local $\frac{0.664}{\sqrt{Re_x}}$ vs Average Drag Coefficient $\frac{1.328}{\sqrt{Re_L}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

The original question is as shown below:

[image]

**My Solution:**

I solved this question and got $0.38 N$ for both sides of the plate but the correct answer as per the test is $\color{red}{ \;0.76 N}$
The only difference between the asnwers is that I used the formula of local drag coefficient $$C_f=\frac{0.664}{\sqrt{Re_x}}$$
$$F_D=2\cdot\frac12C_D\rho AU^2=0.00094(1000)(0.15\cdot3)(3^3)=0.38 N$$
and in the solution they used $$C_D=\frac{1.328}{\sqrt{Re_L}}$$

> **My Concern and Observation:** Which formula should we use according to this question and in **general sense also.**
> I thought, when we consider full length of the object we use $C_D$ and when not full length then we use $C_f$
> Maybe I am wrong, if so, please let me know **when to use which equation??**

Comment: Great observation, I didn't think about this, let me check.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. The question is what keywords to look for to determine when to use $C_D$ vs. $C_f$. Generally, if there’s no reason not to, use $C_D$. That’s because using $C_D$ of a shape in the appropriate equation will return the frictional energy losses or pressure losses due to friction. If unspecified, use $C_D$. However, if the question mentions “one side of” or “calculate the drag/pressure drop on one side” the answer will probably use $C_f$. The best bet is to draw a diagram, and if fluid is flowing around the whole object, use $C_D$, and if fluid is flowing just on one side of the object, consider using $C_f$. So, in this case, because “one side” is not specified, you would use $C_D$.

I found [a study guide](http://www2.latech.edu/%7Esajones/June/Study%20Guides/ChVIIa.pdf) which uses $C_f$ for local drag and $C_D$ for total drag on the object (a plate):
[image: formulae for drag on a flat rectangular plate]

In my experience, $C_D$ generally means the total drag on an object, [whether the object is a cylinder, sphere, plate, person, or any other object you can imagine.](http://tec-science.com/mechanics/gases-and-liquids/drag-coefficient-friction-and-pressure-drag/)

So, $F_d =12ρ⋅U_∞^2⋅A⋅C_D$ (units of force, or mass $\times$ length $\times$ time$^-$ $^2$ e.g. newtons)

**$C_D$ is found by integrating $C_{f_x}$ over the length of an object.**

Comment: The correct answer is 0.76N, because there is drag of 0.38N on each side (top and bottom) of the plate and two times 0.38N is 0.76N. So you can imagine using $C_f$ and doubling it, or using $C_D$; the answers are equivalent; 0.76N.

Comment: That's no the question, carefully read it, it's about only coefficient value.

Comment: The coefficient is dobuled... 1.328 is double 0.664. Don't accuse me of not reading your question, instead clarify what you're asking and what you're after.

Comment: Your assumption that $C_f$ and $C_D$ have different uses is correct, but you didn't quite get what the difference is. The difference is that **$C_f$ is for local drag and $C_D$ is for total drag on an object.**

Comment: I knew that but my question is when it is not given in the question to use local coefficient , what are the keywords which tells us that we need o use local coefficient here?? And I knew that fact that coefficient is doubled I am just Looking for keywords which tells in this question or in general when to use local coefficient

Comment: Ok. I added a paragraph at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Where you said CD for both sides, then there is no need to multiply by an extra 2 ? CD is not for both sides it is used for one side also, your last line is correct! But the starting part is incorrect.